# Check culture of Excel file to parse decimal numbers in .Net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have to import data from Excel files generated on different countries so different parse solutions have to be applied if numbers come with decimal comma or with decimal dot.
Somehow Excel files must include a property to identify the culture they have been generated with.
Is there any way to get it from Vb.Net or C#?

This is my code if I know the file uses decimal commas (requires EPPlus):

```
Dim WorkSheet As OfficeOpenXML.ExcelWorksheet = myWorkSheet
Dim cell As ExcelRange = WorkSheet.Cells(row, col)
Dim cellValue as Object= cell.Value
Dim retval as Decimal = Decimal.Parse(cellValue,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES"))
```

Comment: Can't you use ```Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel``` so that you don't need to parse numbers by yourself? Or maybe the source file is not in a good shape?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If the numbers are stored as numeric values then you should find that no parsing is required - the value is stored in a standard format & only formatted when displayed.

Comment: @PaulF just edited to show what tried so far

Comment: If you are not using C# then you should remove that tag. As I said in my first comment - numbers are stored in a standard format & formatting applied to the cells. Have you tried opening the file in Excel & looking at the cell formatting used. If EPPlus is using that formatting then you maybe able to modify the formatting for the ExcelRange object.